# MFC C++ How do I display a const char value in MessageBox?

Tags: c++, mfc, char, cstring

I hope that the title was good enough to help explain what is needed. After solving this much of my project should be done.

When I did this

```
    char e[1000] = "HELLO";
    CString msg;
    msg.Format(_T("%s"), e);
    MessageBox(msg);
```

the messagebox just show me random words like "㹙癞鞮㹙癞鞮" instead of the "HELLO" i wanted. How do I solve this problem??

Helps would be appreciated.
Thank You

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, are you really using MessageBox API that way. Check the [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
Now to your question,

```
char e[1000] = "HELLO";
CString msg;
msg.Format(_T("%S"), e); // Mind the caps "S"
MessageBox( NULL, msg, _T("Hi"), NULL );
```

I think, you do not even need to `Format` data here. You can use::

```
TCHAR e[1000] = _T("HELLO") ;
MessageBox( NULL, e, _T("Hi"), NULL ) ;
```

This way, if `_UNICODE is defined`, both `TCHAR and MessageBox` would get chosen as `WCHAR and MessageBoxW` and if `not defined` as `char and MessageBoxA`.

Comment: `AfxMessageBox` work for me, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738503/mfc-c-how-do-i-display-a-const-char-value-in-messagebox